# Solving more than one active objective defined for input model in Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, google-colaboratory, pyomo

I am working on an optimization problem based on a kind of "historical memory", ie the only decision variable takes into account its "historical" value at the previous index or indexes. Specifically, I get the following table of objectives:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySgmn.png

The same is also true for the constraints, all depending on the same variable newTr for certain indices.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhHr.png

The problem is that when I try to solve the model I get the following error: *ValueError: More than one active objective defined for input model; Cannot write legal LP file
Objectives: obj[1] obj[2]*

The var newTr is defined as:

model.newTr = pyo.Var(month, bounds = (0, 5), domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, initialize = 0)

The obj function is defined as:

```
    def obj(model, i):
if   i == 1 :
    return cost_att*(initial_att - model.resig[i]) + cost_tr*model.newTr[i]
elif i == 2 :
    return cost_att*(initial_att - model.resig[i]) + cost_tr*(model.newTr[i-1] + model.newTr[i])
else :
    return cost_att*(initial_att - model.resig[i] + model.newTr[i-2]) + cost_tr*(model.newTr[i-1] + model.newTr[i])
```

model.obj = pyo.Objective(month, rule=obj)

How can i solve it?

Comment: I don't think Pyomo can handle multi-objective problems. So you have to do this yourself. E.g. by a weighted sum, or lexicographic. Doing this yourself is actually a good exercise.

Comment: So do you suggest that I consider a new variable for each index? That is, for example for newTr [1] = x1 and so on? For the resolution with cbc solver how should I do?

Comment: I don't think I am suggesting that.